# Python3 string conversion issue

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, type-conversion

I have a function:

```
def push(push):
   ser.write(push + '\r')
   pull = ser.read(11)  
   return pull
```

and i call it like this:

```
out = push("ka " + dp_id + " ff")
```

It turns out to work very well with python2 but when I use python 3 I get the Error:

> unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'ka 01
>   ff\r'

Now if I do this:

```
out = push(b"ka " + display_id + " ff")
```

I get the Error:

> can't concat bytes to str

Im confused. What does help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with `push` itself. You write:

```
b"ka " + display_id + " ff"
# ^bytes ^string      ^string
```

(the `b` prefix says you actually write a sequence of bytes).

so that won't work. You can *encode* a string to a byte array with `.encode()` and use the `b` prefix on the last string. So:

```
b"ka " + display_id.encode() + b" ff"
# ^bytes ^bytes                ^bytes
```